# How to convert image into webp using gm in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, webp, gm

I was using `gm` for resizing images. Now I learn about `webp` to speed up my site. So I want to convert images into `webp` using same library. But the following does not work.

How can I convert images into `webp` by `gm`?

```
function resize(last) {
    self.resize(width, height)
    .quality(80)
    .strip()
    .gravity('Center')
    .toBuffer(imageType, function(err, buffer) {
        if (err) last(err);
        else last(null, buffer);
    });
},
```

**EDIT**

```
gm('thumb_3.JPG')
  .toBuffer('webp', (err, buffer) => {
  fs.writeFile('buffer.webp', buffer, console.log)
})
```

I use this code also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is call:

```
.toBuffer('webp', (err, buffer) => { /* ... */ })
```

Or using `streams`

```
.stream('webp');
```

But for it to work, you have to install imagick explicitly with webp

```
brew install imagemagick --with-webp
```

---

Otherwise install `graphicsmagick` that supports `webp` directly.

Depending on your OS:

**Ubuntu/Debian**

```
sudo apt-get install graphicsmagick
```

**Mac OS**

```
brew install graphicsmagick
```

For windows or other OS, check:

- [GraphicsMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/)

---

Working example:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const gm = require('gm');

gm('/tmp/img.jpg')
  .stream('webp')
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('/tmp/img.webp'));

gm('/tmp/img.jpg')
  .toBuffer('webp', (err, buffer) => {
    fs.writeFile('/tmp/img-buffer.webp', buffer, console.log)
  })
```

Comment: it only change format , not reduces sizes like other libraries

Comment: Yes It does, it reduces it's size. Anyway that depends on the image, maybe there isn't anything to optimize. I just tested with a `14.5kb` `jpg` that when converted to `webp` got reduced to `2.3kb`. Anyway you asked how to convert to `webp` which my response clearly answers that question.

Comment: by which you test it

Comment: your answer seems right but unfortunately it not working on my end

Comment: it just print null and create empty webp files

Comment: Show all your code, you're probably using the error value of the callback. Or you don't have the right dependency installed.

Comment: What does console.log(buffer) outputs?, which OS are you using? Do you have graphicsmagick? Or imagemagick?

Comment: it logs null
and create empty webp file
I am on ubuntu 14.04....yes I have both of them

Comment: gm("input.jpg").write("output33.png", function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
});

Comment: this one converts it but I want to use buffer

Comment: And what does console.log(err) shows? If buffer is null, then error must not be null..

Comment: And you can't have both. Do `gm --version` and show me which version of graphicsmagick are you using.

Comment: gm  version is 1.23.1

Comment: GraphicsMagick-config --version is 1.3.18

Comment: console.log outputs : Stream yields empty buffer

Comment: The `err` throws : `Stream yields empty buffer`?

Answer (score 2):

For me, I am using gm version `1.3.30` and it does not include `webp` automatically. instead, you need to install it manually

To check, `gm -version`

```
Feature Support:
  Native Thread Safe       yes
  Large Files (> 32 bit)   yes
  Large Memory (> 32 bit)  yes
  BZIP                     yes
  ...
  WebP                     no
  WMF                      no
  X11                      no
  XML                      yes
  ZLIB                     yes
```

to install with brew,

```
brew install graphicsmagick --with-webp
```

if you already installed it before then

```
brew reinstall graphicsmagick --with-webp
```

including `webp` will solve the issue `Stream yields empty buffer` as well.

good luck !

Comment: How i can install webp on debian?

Comment: sudo apt install webp

Comment: i am using windows linux subsystem. in my case i had to install webp package. --with-wepb option was not supported.